# ¿Cómo cambiar el tamaño de un iframe?

Tags: iframe

Implementé un mapa a mi página de [WordPress](https://es.wordpress.com/) por medio de un `iframe` el problema es que estoy intentando cambiar de tamaño a mi iframe y nada funciona.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.10.7:8686/mapa_zonas/maps.html" width="1000" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

En tu código, al atributo `height` le falta la comilla de cierre, quedando así:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.10.7:8686/mapa_zonas/maps.html" width="1000" height="1000" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es con CSS (abajo) y es recomendable que para hacerlo responsive no se use **px** sino **vw** o **vh** o **%** y para la W3C los atributos height y width en HTML ya son obsoletos así que es mejor usar CSS.

```css
iframe{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  /*Sólo para que se vea, ya que la dirección al parecer está mal*/
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="http://192.168.10.7:8686/mapa_zonas/maps.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices la API de google:

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp

Podras utilizar la etiqueta div, que es un poco mas flexible con los estilos.